# methods of getting request to the server?

Tags: http

There are two methods of getting request to the server .one is the get method and the other is the head method.please any one can explain them.thanks

Comment: Actually, there's a few more methods than just those...

Comment: You probably should say *which* protocol you're interested in - you might mean HTTP; but if so, you've missed **many** of the methods used by HTTP...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are talking about the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP). In the HTTP protocol HEAD is very similar to GET but with HEAD the server will only send the *headers* and not the content.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html